# How does the script_loader_tag function works?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen script_loader_tag function applied in functions.php, WordPress, but I struggle to understand completely how does it work.

For example, I've seen examples like this:

```
function add_async_defer($tag, $handle) {

    if('googlemaps' !== $handle) {
        return $tag;
    }
    return str_replace(' src', 'async="async" defer="defer" src', $tag);
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_defer', 10, 2);
```

and it is used to generate the script tag for Google Maps API:

```
<script type='text/javascript'async="async" defer="defer" src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBz02VRxO_dgaKsBS62TLL6AW4McNTQiKU&#048;callback=initMap&#038;ver=5.2.1'></script>
```

But what does the $tag and $handle parameters mean?

What does numbers 10 and 2 mean in the end of the add_filter?

Can this function be modified to display the  tag conditionally only in the specific pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters are as defined below:

**$tag**: The  tag for the enqueued script.

**$handle**: The script's registered handle. For example the jQuery enqueued by WordPress has the handle 'jquery'

The numeric **10** represents the priority of the callback function in WordPress queue to process all the functions hooked on the `script_loader_tag` hook.

The numeric **2** represents the number of parameters allowed in callback function.

@chinLeung answered with reference as well.

---

Considering your code example the following should explain things further:

```
function add_async_defer($tag, $handle, $src) {
    if('googlemaps' !== $handle) {//Here we check if our handle is googlemaps
        return $tag; //We return the entire <script> tag as is without modifications.
    }
    return "<script type='text/javascript' async='async' defer='defer' src='".$src."'></script>";//Usually the value in $tag variable looks similar to this script tag but without the async and defer
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_async_defer', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For example, I have 4 pages: HOME, ABOUT, EVENTS and CONTACT. Can I use this function conditionally for the script tag to appear only on HOME and CONTACT pages, because now it appears on all of the pages. Could you pleas supplement your answer with an example?

Comment: For script to appear only on certain pages you better place conditional checks before enqueuing them.

Comment: Tnx. That helped.

Answer (score 2):

The `$handle` is the name you've given to the script when you use `wp_enqueue_script`.

The `$tag` is the script tag that is going to be rendered in the DOM.

The `10` is the priority of your filter. Changing to a higher number would make the filter executed later in the process.

And finally the `2` is the number of arguments that the callback is accepting. In your case, it's 2 as there is `$tag` and `$handle`.

For more information:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For example, I have 4 pages: HOME, ABOUT, EVENTS and CONTACT. Can I use this function conditionally for the script tag to appear only on HOME and CONTACT pages, because now it appears on all of the pages. Could you pleas supplement your answer with an example?

Comment: Yes, you should check for the page with is_page( int|string|int[]|string[] $page = '' ) and write conditional code

You can do this inside the function attached to the filter.